# iOS: Flash based programming app for iOS?

Tags: ios, flash

I would like to know, Is there way to support Flash based programming app for iOS? It can be native, hybrid or web app. I like to know, is there any possibility to develop Flash based app for iOS devices? I have seen the forums and saying everywhere it is not possible, so just want to confirm before starting any development.

Thank you.

Comment: in last year, it is impossible. But in recent update of Flash, the App approval status is APPROVED. ( though I believe Apple will reject those apps in future )

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, do you mean Flash supported web apps are approved by Apple now to show on iOS devices? Could you share the link please?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create multiplatform native apps with flash if you use adobe air

[More info about Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html)

Comment: maybe you can add more description about Adobe AIR, and its requirement, e.g. requires Apple Developer Program account

Comment: that isn't really an Adobe AIR requirement, the Apple Developer Program account is a requirement for developing iOS apps, you need it if you use objective-c, rubymotion, phonegap, AIR and any other software for creating native or hybrid apps. And the link explains what Adobe AIR is