# It is possible now to create iOS application via Adobe Flash?

Tags: ios, iphone, flash, actionscript, adobe

Can I create the iPhone application using Adobe Flash now?
Can't find information about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about: http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html

> Using Flash Professional CS6 and other Adobe tools, you can easily publish and package iOS and Android apps.

Previously asked at [iOS: Flash based programming app for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009218/ios-flash-based-programming-app-for-ios)

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) should work. FlashDevelop is your programming IDE.

Comment: Also look at the Haxe language. It looks like flash, compiles for many platforms.